# Guzzle 6 doesn't work with TLS1.2

Tags: php, curl, guzzle, guzzle6

A little background first: for some reason, making `curl` calls inside my Vagrant machine works only if I use --tlsv1.2 option, without that I get:

```
cURL error 35: SSL connect error (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

So I've put that value into configuration file, `~/.curlrc`, so every time I run 
`curl https://myapi.com` on the command line that option is used automatically, and it works fine.

However, I am currently playing with Guzzle 6, which uses curl to make API calls in the background. I assumed that curl that `Guzzle` uses will use the same configuration file `~/.curlrc`, but seems not because I'm getting again: `cURL error 35: SSL connect` error.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
$client = new HttpClient(['defaults' => [
            'verify' => false
        ]]);
        $response = $client->request('GET', 'https://myapi.com', ['curl' => [
            CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 6,
        ]]);
```

As you can see, I even tried to pass TLSV1.2 value(value 6 is mapped to TLSV1.2 according to curl php documentation) to curl, but still nothing. Anybodu have an idea what could be wrong here?

EDIT: yeah, just confirmed that Guzzle uses some other curl binary. I moved the original one to another location and can't no longer accessed it from the command line, but after that Guzzle still returns the same error.